# Get U, Sigma, V* matrix from Truncated SVD in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, svd

I am using truncated SVD from `scikit-learn` package.

In the definition of SVD, an original matrix **A** is approxmated as a product **A** ≈ **UΣV*** where **U** and **V** have orthonormal columns, and **Σ** is non-negative diagonal.

I need to get the **U**, **Σ** and **V*** matrices.

Looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/truncated_svd.py#L174) I found out that **V*** is stored in `self.components_` field after calling `fit_transform`.

Is it possible to get **U** and **Σ** matrices?

My code:

```
import sklearn.decomposition as skd
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.random((20,20))
trsvd = skd.TruncatedSVD(n_components=15)
transformed = trsvd.fit_transform(matrix)
VT = trsvd.components_
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Looking into the source via the link you provided, `TruncatedSVD` is basically a wrapper around sklearn.utils.extmath.randomized_svd; you can manually call this yourself like this:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import randomized_svd

U, Sigma, VT = randomized_svd(X, 
                              n_components=15,
                              n_iter=5,
                              random_state=None)
```

Answer (score 11):

One can use [scipy.sparse.svds](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html) (for dense matrices you can use [svd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html#numpy.linalg.svd)).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds

matrix = np.random.random((20, 20))
num_components = 2
u, s, v = svds(matrix, k=num_components)
X = u.dot(np.diag(s))  # output of TruncatedSVD
```

If you're working with really big sparse matrices (perhaps your working with natural text), even `scipy.sparse.svds` might blow up your computer's RAM. In such cases, consider the [sparsesvd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sparsesvd/) package which uses [SVDLIBC](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/SVDLIBC/), and what `gensim` uses [under-the-hood](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/e4114336591e2dcd311260b7b221e2427335417a/gensim/models/lsimodel.py#L131-L138).

```
import numpy as np
from sparsesvd import sparsesvd


X = np.random.random((30, 30))
ut, s, vt = sparsesvd(X.tocsc(), k)
projected = (X * ut.T)/s
```

Comment: This is true but for the regular numpy.linalg.svd method you can't pass the number of components as a parameter so you have to extract the top K yourself. Minor inconvenience.

Comment: X = u.dot(np.diag(s)) . This will not recreate X as 'v' is missing

Answer (score 9):

Just as a note:

```
svd.transform(X)
```

and

```
svd.fit_transform(X)
```

generate **U * Sigma**.

```
svd.singular_values_
```

generates **Sigma** in vector form.

```
svd.components_
```

generates **VT**.
Maybe we can use

```
svd.transform(X).dot(np.linalg.inv(np.diag(svd.singular_values_)))
```

to get **U** because **U * Sigma * Sigma ^ -1 = U * I = U**.

Answer (score 8):

From the source code, we can see `X_transformed` which is `U * Sigma` (Here `Sigma` is a vector) is returned 
from the `fit_transform` method. So we can get

```
svd = TruncatedSVD(k)
X_transformed = svd.fit_transform(X)

U = X_transformed / svd.singular_values_
Sigma_matrix = np.diag(svd.singular_values_)
VT = svd.components_
```

**Remark**

Truncated SVD is an approximation. X ≈ X' = UΣV*. We have X'V = UΣ. But what about XV? An interesting fact is XV = X'V. This can be proved by comparing the full SVD form of X and the truncated SVD form of X'. Note XV is just `transform(X)`, so we can also get `U` by

```
U = svd.transform(X) / svd.singular_values_
```

Answer (score 0):

If your matrices are not large, since numpy computes SVD by sorting singular values in order, this can be computed directly with [`np.linalg.svd`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) simply by taking the first k singular values from Σ, first k columns of U, and first k rows of Vh. (Use `full_matrices=False` to get thin SVD if one of your dimensions is huge.)

```
m = np.random.random((5,5))
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(m)
u2, s2, vh2 = u[:,:2], s[:2], vh[:2,:]
m2 = u2 @ np.diag(s2) @ vh2  # rank-2 approx
```

If your matrices are large, then the randomized algorithms provided by [`sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) will compute truncated SVD more efficiently.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an older question but the correct version is-

```
U = svd.fit_transform(X)
Sigma = svd.singular_values_
VT = svd.components_
```

However, one thing to keep in mind is that U and VT are truncated hence without the rest of the values it not possible to recreate X.

Comment: U is definitely not `svd.fit_transform(X) `. This is wrong.

Answer (score -5):

Let us suppose X is our input matrix on which we want yo perform Truncated SVD.
Below commands helps to find out the U, Sigma and VT :

```
    from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

    SVD = TruncatedSVD(n_components=r) 
    U = SVD.fit_transform(X)
    Sigma = SVD.explained_variance_ratio_
    VT = SVD.components_
    #r corresponds to the rank of the matrix
```

To understand the above terms, please refer to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html

Comment: I believe this answer is not correct: `SVD.fit_transform(X) = U*np.diag(Sigma) != U` and `SVD.explained_variance_ratio_ = np.var(X_transformed, axis=0) / np.var(X, axis=0).sum()  != Sigma`

Comment: This answer is not correct, as mentioned by rth as well.